# Keep file in temporary dir using sys_get_temp_dir in PHP script

Tags: php, apache2, temp

I'm calling an RPC API function that creates a file in a temp dir whose path is made concatenating PHP temp dir (In GNU/Linux, `/tmp`), returned by `sys_get_temp_dir` function, and a string.

But when the PHP script finishes the file has gone. It appears that PHP removes the file after the script is ran.

Is there a way to keep the file after running PHP script?

Comment: Linux will normally clear the `/tmp` directory on reboot, but PHP does not.  How are you creating the file?

Comment: Now I see that in fact PHP script is creating the file in `/tmp` of the Apache temp dir. The file is not being removed. Thanks for clarify any way.